# Fail2Ban login filter not working on Debian Web Server

Tags: linux, security, debian, fail2ban, ids

So I am having issues getting Fail2Ban to work with as a custom filter for a web app login. First of all, other filter do work such as NGINX Auth. However, my emails have stopped working, not sure why yet.

These are the failed login attempts in the /var/log/auth.log

```
Apr  1 11:28:15 user pancake[17973]: Attempt to login as random failed. 127.0.0.1 (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17)

Apr  1 11:28:39 user pancake[17974]: Attempt to login as admin failed. 127.0.0.1 (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17)
```

My Jail (/etc/fail2ban/jail.local):

```
[pancake]

enabled  = true

port     = http,https

filter   = pancake

logpath  = /var/log/auth.log

maxretry = 4
```

My filter (/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/pancak.conf)

```
[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from

# common.local

before = common.conf

[Definition]

_daemon = pancake

failregex = Attempt to login as .* failed. <HOST>$

ignoreregex =
```

Now when I test by running:

```
sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/pancake.conf
```

I get:

```
Running tests

=============

Use   failregex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/pancake.conf

Use         log file : /var/log/auth.log

Results

=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

|- [# of hits] date format

|  [2708] MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second

`-

Lines: 2708 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 2708 missed
```

I have also tried using:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)sAttempt to login as .* failed. <HOST>$
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Trent

Comment: Why are you using an end-of-line (`$`) in the regex while there is no end-of-line at that point in the log file auth.log (but rather the parenthesis containing the user agent etc.)?

Comment: @Marki Hey yep this fixed it however, now it's not banning it after failed attempts. This is the same problem I am having with my Wordpress (WP Fail2ban - plugin) logs work, fail2ban-regex works however no banning is working. I am assuming this to be something with the action. But I'm new to fail2ban and am learning it. Cheers

Comment: disregard my last. I restarted fail2ban and all good. Thanks

Comment: You would have had to ask a new question anyways as noone here is looking in comments for new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `$` from the regex as in the log there is no end of line at that point.